# JDBC + ScriptRunner : error with runScript

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to use [ScriptRunner](https://gist.github.com/831762/) to execute a sql script file with a JDBC driver.
I can initiate ScriptRunner but I can't execute the runScript line :

```
ScriptRunner runner = new ScriptRunner(c, false, false);
runner.runScript("C:/Users/Pierre/Documents/create.sql");
```

The error is :

> cannot find symbol method
>   runScript(java.lang.String) || line 41

The connection with the database is fine.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class ConnectPostgreSQL {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
  System.out.println("Checking if Driver is registered with DriverManager.");

  try {
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
    System.out.println("Couldn't find the driver!");
    System.out.println("Let's print a stack trace, and exit.");
    cnfe.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(1);
  }

  System.out.println("Registered the driver ok, so let's make a connection.");

  Connection c = null;

  try {
    // The second and third arguments are the username and password,
    // respectively. They should be whatever is necessary to connect
    // to the database.
    c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres", "postgres", "passroot");
  } catch (SQLException se) {
    System.out.println("Couldn't connect: print out a stack trace and exit.");
    se.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(1);
  }

  if (c != null)
    System.out.println("Hooray! We connected to the PostgreSQL database!");
  else
    System.out.println("We should never get here.");

  //temps t1
  long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
  System.out.println(begin);

  ScriptRunner runner = new ScriptRunner(c, false, false);
  runner.runScript("C:/Users/Pierre/Documents/create.sql");

  //temps t2
  long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
  System.out.println(end);

  //différence de t2 - t1
  float time = ((float) (end-begin)) / 1000f;
  System.out.println(time);
  }
}
```

Can somebody help me ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It's because runScript method hasn't in argument String, look to [ScriptRunner code](https://gist.github.com/831762/)

```
public void runScript(Reader reader)
```

Change your

```
runner.runScript("C:/Users/Pierre/Documents/create.sql");
```

To:

```
try {
    FileReader reader = new FileReader("C:/Users/Pierre/Documents/create.sql");
    runner.runScript(reader);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and add imports like

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer !
But I don't understand what this "Reader reader" is exactely. How can I launch my file the easiest way ?

Answer (score 0):

The `runScript` method of ScriptRunner takes a [Reader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) as an argument, so you need to change line 41 to

```
try {
runner.runScript(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/Pierre/Documents/create.sql")));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and add imports like

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
```

Comment: I get "cannot find symbol class BufferedReader" and "cannot find symbol class FileReader" with this. :-(

Comment: You need to import them like import java.io.BufferedReader; import java.io.FileReader They are both part of Java IO Package.

Comment: I have edited my answer to add the imports. Let us know in case you face further problems.

Comment: I get "unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown" and "unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown" now. Thanks for the help ! I really appreciate it.

Comment: It means that the file create.sql doesn't exist in C:/Users/Pierre/Documents/create.sql. If you are running this from windows, try using C://Users//Pierre//Documents//create.sql instead.

Comment: The path is right. I tried both solutions with the file at the root "C:/create.sql" and "C://create.sql" : same problems. :'(

Comment: Catch the exception and let me know what it is and where do you get that exception. try {runner.runScript("C:/Users/Pierre/Documents/create.sql"); } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); } }

Comment: Have updated my code snippet above. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: I tried : try { runner.runScript(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/create.sql"))); } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }. It works but I got a weird output : http://pastebin.com/ufQCpX0k

Comment: Between "System.out.println(begin);" and "System.out.println(end);". See the output here : http://pastebin.com/ufQCpX0k

Comment: Sorry, I added some lines : http://pastebin.com/K8WR1NjQ Line 45 is "runner.runScript(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/create.sql")));".

Answer (score 0):

ScriptRunner send line by line to DB. When the script has a delimiter ($$, &&, ||), the line is automatically executed. To fix this, you need to use the last version of [ScriptRunner](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3) and set to send full script (runner.setSendFullScript(true)).